# TensorFlow from Google - Data Security

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-developer-tools

Does anyone have any idea whether Google collects data that one supplies to Tensorflow? I mean it is open source, but it falls under their licences.

Comment: Please do tell why exactly downvote? If it concerns a topic that could go either way and concerns safety of given files ?

Comment: Why downvote? Because the question shows that you have not researched the subject. Simply searching for "tensorflow license" would reveal that it's just an Apache licence. Since it's also open source, there's hardly any risk of leaking information (as also explained in answer by @lejlot).

Answer (score 3):

You can read the whole code of TF. There is nothing there that sends any data, thus the answer is **no**, there is no data collection. TF is not a service but a library, thus having an open source gives you full guarantee whether anything "bad" is happening to your data.

> falls under their licences

I do not understand what do you mean by that. TensorFlow [is released under Apache 2.0 license](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/LICENSE). There is no such thing as "their licences" (you mean Google?).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't TF actually also uses google's models from cloud? I'm pretty sure google uses cloud data to provide better models for TF.

I'd recommend you to stay away from it. Only by writing your models from scratch you will learn to do useful stuff with it long term. I can also recommend weka for java, it's open source and you can only look at the code of the models there an implement it yourself adjusting for your needs.